# MongoDB 3.4.5: Hyphen-Minus does not work with $text searches

Tags: mongodb, search

I use MongoDB, Version 3.4.5 and I tried to exclude a term with -(minus).
For any reason it does not work.
These are my tries:

```
db.Product.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("59cbfcd01889a9fd89a3565c"), "name" : "Produkt Neu", ...
    { "_id" : ObjectId("59cc7d941889a4f4c2f43b14"), "name" : "Produkt2", ...

db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: 'Produkt -Neu' } } );

db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt -Neu" } } );

db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt2" } } );
    { "_id" : ObjectId("59cc7d941889a4f4c2f43b14"), "name" : "Produkt2", ...

db.Product.dropIndexes()

db.Product.createIndex({ name: "text" })
    {
        "nIndexesWas" : 2,
        "msg" : "non-_id indexes dropped for collection",
        "ok" : 1
    }

    {
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
    }

db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt -Neu" } } );

db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt Neu" } } );
    { "_id" : ObjectId("59cbfcd01889a9fd89a3565c"), "name" : "Produkt Neu", ...
```

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to get it work with -(minus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a collection: `Product` with the following documents ...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0ada3c26584cd8b79fc51"),
    "name" : "Produkt Neu"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0adafc26584cd8b79fc54"),
    "name" : "Produkt2"
}
```

... and I declared a text index on this collection as follows:

```
db.Product.createIndex({ name: "text" })
```

I ran the following queries which faithfully reproduce the situation described in your question:

```
// returns one document since there is one document 
// which has the text indexed value: "Produkt Neu"
db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt Neu" } } );

// returns no documents since there is no document 
// which has the text indexed value: "Produkt2"
db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt -Neu" } } )
```

You are, I think, expecting this query ...

```
db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt -Neu" } } )
```

... to return the second document on the grounds that excluding `Neu` should allow a match on the document having `name=Produkt2` but this is not how MongoDB `$text` searches work. MongoDB `$text` searches **do not support partial matching** so the search term `Produkt -Neu` (which evaluates as `Produkt`) will not match `Produkt2`. To verify this, I ran the following query:

```
db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt2 -Neu" } } )
```

This query returns the second document (i.e. the one with `name=Produkt2`) which proves that the hyphen-minus (`-`) successfully negated the term: `Neu`.

On a side note; MongoDB text indexes do support language stemming, to verify this behaviour I added the following document...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0b2b4c26584cd8b79fd7c"),
    "name" : "Produkts"
}
```

...and then ran this query ...

```
db.Product.find( { $text: { $search: "Produkt -Neu" } } );
```

This query returns the document with `name=Produkts` because `Product` is a stem of `Produkts`.

In summary, a `$text` search will find matches where each search term has either (a) a match on a whole world in the text index or (b) is a recognised stem of a whole word in the text index. Note: there are also phrase matches but those are not relevant to the examples in your question. Use of the hyphen-minus serves to change the search terms but it does not change how the search term is evaluated.

More details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and there is an open issue with MongoDB relating to [supporting partial matching on text indexes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15090).

If you really need to support partial matching then you'll probably want to discard the text index and use the `$regex` operator instead. Though it's worth noting that index coverage with the `$regex` operator is probably not what you expect, the brief summary is this: if your search value is anchored (i.e. `Produk`, rather than `rodukt`) then MongoDB can use an index but otherwise it cannot.